Prohibit workflow dispatch from running on branches other than main
I would like to prevent GitHub Action's workflow dispatch to only work on the main branch. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: 
      - main

When I go to the Github actions screen to run the pipeline manually, I can also try to run it on the other branches. Ideally, I would like to forbid running this job (publishing) on any non-main branch.
Is there any way I can enforce this?
For reference, the pipeline is part of this YML. You can also see the publish job running on Test branch on the Actions screen.

Why do you need to restrict it to just the main branch? This is a manual action, you can just not run it on the other branches.

@CorneliusRoemer he probably works in a team with other humans. Humans make mistakes.

Then just add a step where you fail the job if it is run on a branch other than main. Also, him saying "I work on a personal project" means he works on this alone and not in a team.

The example is for a personal project. However, this thing happened in our team a couple of days ago by accident and I am just investigating how to fix this or to enforce the policy.

" I have used the following snippet to get this behavior." - Your snippet is not valid, or at least isn't from the docs, you likely wrongly combined some things together that aren't supposed to be combined like this.

@Grimson I had the exact same issue two weeks ago at work where someone ran a release workflow from master. It's definitively valid to add branch protection on the jobs.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to restrict what branch an action can be run on?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe the question is different. I was specifically investigating why workflow dispatch also shows the job for other branches if I already have a filter branches: - main.

It's the same thing, but I see GitHub have actually introduced specific syntax for this since that question was asked. You might want to check the workflow_run  syntax too

I see. Thanks for the workflow_run syntax suggestion. I shall look more into it.

@Grimson where did you find that the branches filter is supported on workflow dispatch? I have not found this anywhere, definitely not in the docs link you shared.

You can add a if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' to your job that'll prevent it from running on a given branch.
Or like if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/release') if you want to only run on your release branches
Example:
jobs:
  Setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      ...

Alternatively you might also be able to use the workflow_run syntax, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-when-your-workflow-runs/events-that-trigger-workflows#limiting-your-workflow-to-run-based-on-branches

Does this mean that the branches: - main has no effect on running the job on just one pipeline? What even is the purpose of this is then?

The if will skip the job in question if it's run from a wrong branch. It'll show up as "This job was skipped" in GitHub

Yes, this branches main for workflow dispatch isn't in the docs, it's for other triggers, your syntax is likely not valid.

The syntax is, as mentioned, for jobs. Not for the workflow_dispatch.

Can you also suggest what the correct syntax should be?

@Grimson I've updated the answer now with clarification

Thank you. Can you also tell me which actions trigger workflow dispatch where branches: - main works and what the correct syntax of writing it is?

@Grimson you misunderstood. The dropdown to run it on any given branch will remain, you can't avoid that. But the job won't do anything if you run it on a invalid branch.

I understand that. I wanted to know if workflow dispatch can be triggered by other events too? If I need to add the if statement check to my jobs, I want to know why I need to specify branches at all.

What do you mean by your last statement? Specify branches at all? Specify what where?
